# XSLT - how to remove one email address if it has two email addresses

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

In the below xslt  I may get two emailaddress values at runtime like Redemptions@test.com;helpdesk@test.com

```
<xsl:element name="FROM">
<xsl:value-of select="*/EMAIL_ADDRESS"/>
</xsl:element>
```

I need to check if there are two addresses and remove the first one before semicolon(;) I can't send email from two email addresses.

Comment: Please show the input data you have, the XSLT you have shown does not output any semicolon as far as I can tell.

Comment: `substring-after('Redemptions@test.com;helpdesk@test.com', ';')` will return `'helpdesk@test.com'`.

Comment: @kjhughes It is required semicolon validation, e.g. with <xsl:choose> as in case if there is only one mail with substring-after(*/EMAIL_ADDRESS, ';') it will return empty block as <FROM/>.

Answer (score 0):

To check if there are two mails or only one you can use `<xsl:choose>` inside of `<xsl:element name="FROM">` block, then if there is more than one mail use `substring-after(*/EMAIL_ADDRESS, ';')`, see below:

```
    <xsl:element name="FROM">            
        <xsl:choose>
            <!--check if semicolon exists - will mean that there is more than one mail-->
            <xsl:when test="contains(*/EMAIL_ADDRESS, ';')">                     
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!--check if after first semicolon there is one more and take value before it-->
                    <xsl:when test="contains(substring-after(*/EMAIL_ADDRESS, ';'), ';')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(*/EMAIL_ADDRESS, ';'), ';')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!--get second mail after semicolon-->
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(*/EMAIL_ADDRESS, ';')"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>                    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!--otherwise it simply takes value of */EMAIL_ADDRESS-->
                <xsl:value-of select="*/EMAIL_ADDRESS"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>           
    </xsl:element>
```

Result as expected:

```
<FROM>helpdesk@test.com</FROM>
```